# Fail to pull Azure DevOps repository called by T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-devops, pull-request, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to build some automation which will compare my SQL Server databases against git repository, stored on Azure DevOps.
There is a simple ps script, stored in a file, which works like a charm when I call it from Powershell command line:

> D:\SSDT\Production\SQL02> D:\SSDT\ps_scripts\UpdRepo.ps1
> warning: redirecting to https://someaddress.visualstudio.com/someaddress/_git/anotherurl/
> Already up to date.

Now I want to call that ps file from a SQL Stored Procedure, using:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe "E:\SSDT\ps_scripts\UpdRepo.ps1"'
```

And all I get is:

> git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At E:\SSDT\ps_scripts\UpdRepo.ps1:2 char:1
> git pull
>
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> NULL

I did add
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
to system environment variables but SQL Engine seems ignoring those

I tried different syntax but got the same error messages
Tried to run script on SSMS and with SQL job

Any suggestion with how can I introduce git command to SQL engine or alternative way to call git pull command from SQL Server, or perhaps calling ps without SQL Engine try to parse it, will be appreciated!
SQL Server 2019  Enterprise addition

Comment: I don't have much experience with xp_cmdshell, but probably the problem is that the stored procedure uses different credentials and therefore git may not be in the PATH env variable

Comment: @mnieto
You are right. Once I switched SQL Server service authentication from NT Service\MSSQLSERVER to domain user, it did the trick. Thank you so much.